# What exactly here is getting permeated in Maggie words?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Source is *St Vincent (2014)* comedy movie.

Context: At Saint school, Principle and Brother Geragathy talking to
Maggie about her son Oliver's behavoir.

> Maggie: We're in the middle of a divorce. Oliver's father was  having
>   an affair with his assistant, and our accountant, and my hairdresser,
>   while she was still doing my hair, so that was fun. And now he's filed
>   for custody of Oliver, full custody. And he won't pay any support
>   until he gets  what he wants. Plus, he's a lawyer. So I just had to
>   get  out of there as fast as I could, and I took Oliver with me, and I
>   got a job at Mission Hills. I'm a CAT scan tech. So I just see...
>   really rough stuff all day. You know, cancer and tumors and cysts and
>   clots, and I see  what I'm looking at, but I can't tell, you know, the
>   people that are laying there, so that's... miserable all day. And I 
>   work really late, because I'm trying to get our act together. That's
>   why he's here, so he can have a good education, and I'm  trying to
>   just give him a semi-normal life, and I'm dealing with this shit from
>   David and... custody. I'm sorry about swearing. I know he didn't even
>   want kids. He didn't want them. He's just  doing this so I'm not
>   happy. You know Oliver's adopted. I don't  know how you would, but he
>   is. And... I cannot have... kids. You know, something about my
>   fallopian tubes being twisted. I think, what I really think, is that
>   they were just recoiling from David's sperm. Can I...
>
> Maggie: Can I just have one? (Asking for tissue to clean her face)
>
> Maggie: Thank you. Thank you for that. (Brother Geragathy gave her
>   tissue) So I just think that all of this has kind of **permeated**,  you
>   know, Oliver's whole little being, right? I mean, it has to. He's like
>   a little, like a little sponge.

I know the word permeate means It means to spread through something and be 
present in every part of it. For example:

> A foul smell of stale beer **permeated** the whole building.

**Foul smell of stale beer** is occupied **whole building**. So in Maggie words what is occupied what exactly?

Comment: The list of misfortunes (*all of this*) has permeated her son's entire emotional and physical state (*Oliver's whole little being*).

Answer (score 1):

And (to add to @FumbleFingers' answer) what has occupied Oliver's being is all the experiences of the divorce, Maggie's problems dealing with the consequences. In other words, Oliver has grown up with all this and it has affected him deeply.

Answer (score 0):

In the cited context, "what is occupied" is ***Oliver's whole little being*** - *the entirety of his existence, everything about him.*